# When calculating lexical richness (e.g. TTR) do you lemmatize first?

Tags: nlp

When calculating Type-Token Ration (TTR) and Hapax richness (along with similar measures), do you lemmatize the corpus first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there's no standard way to use [lexical density measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_density) such as Type-Token Ratio (TTR).

It's common to apply TTR to the raw tokenized text, in particular if there is no suitable lemmatizer available or if the lemmatization risks introducing errors. Otherwise there's no strong reason one way or the other, as far as I'm aware. However it's important to proceed consistently of course: if one wants to compare TTR between different texts, the TTR should have been calculated the same way.